# Is there a standalone library for Google's QUIC?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, protocols

Google recently released their experimental transport protocol called [QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC) as a namespace `net.quic` in Chrome. I'd love to use it, as it looks perfect for my use case, however I can't seem to find any guide on using it as a standalone library.

Is there any available way to get QUIC as a standalone library aside from the Chrome source?

[Google Slide Deck](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13LSNCCvBijabnn1S4-Bb6wRlm79gN6hnPFHByEXXptk/edit#slide=id.g176a9a2e9_0143)

Comment: as of May 2019, look at: https://quiche.googlesource.com/quiche/
it is Google's official extraction of the quic code. It should be the most up to date.

Comment: there are many, and the Quic Working Group is maintaining a list at https://github.com/quicwg/base-drafts/wiki/Implementations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Tue 5 Apr, 2016, Google has released their own [proto-quic library on Github](https://github.com/google/proto-quic).

Comment: as of May 2019, look at: https://quiche.googlesource.com/quiche/
it is Google's official extraction of the quic code. It should be the most up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [LiteSpeed QUIC Client Library](https://github.com/litespeedtech/lsquic-client).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, Given how fast QUIC is evolving (see slide 6 in that deck https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13LSNCCvBijabnn1S4-Bb6wRlm79gN6hnPFHByEXXptk/edit#slide=id.g2af01bdeb_050) hacking QUIC anywhere else except in Chrome/Chromium would be a recipe for pain -- you'd spend so much time keeping up to date with Google changes to QUIC that your productivity would plummet.

Comment: This would fit as a comment rather than an answer, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand, this is as close to an answer as there is for now. (And according to meta: answers index/search better than comments)

Comment: This could be best answer. I am currently working on a QUIC implementation for Erlang and the RFCs + Crypto docs are lacking the bulk of the information.  The wireshark caps using chromium and the C++, Go servers paint a completely different story. Pain is the right word, perhaps add suffering. Irregardless that its 2 years later.

Answer (score 0):

Since this Question is almost top in QUIC google questions:

Here is the link to a [libquic project on github](https://github.com/conght/quic).

*edit: Updated the url to the "libquic" chromium code extraction.